# Is it possible to obtain nested folder information in a standard web application without using a browser plugin?

Tags: javascript, html, browser, file-permissions, directory

Having read the answer to this question: 
[How to upload folder in web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7844356/how-to-upload-folder-in-web-application)', is a web application able to browse a folder structure on the client user's machine?

This would be useful to, say, upload all files and subfolders within a nested folder structure without the user having to navigate the entire target folder heirarchy herself.

I assume this is not possible because **HTML/Javascript executing by itself** (not in conjunction with Java or Flash plugin) does not have permission to browse folders the client machine? But some of my colleagues disagree so I want to put the question out there.

If it *is* possible, then how? I'm looking for the theory here, not a full code solution, but not so theoretical that you've never verified it.

Comment: You are correct. You wouldn't want code being executed in a browser to see your local files. That'd be a giant security risk. There were/are ways to do this with browser plugins but not with any native web technologies by themselves (which is a good thing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer: Not possible

Since no one has answered and I haven't been able to find a hint of doubt reading through W3C specs and IEFT HTML and HTTP RFCs I am 99% sure this is not possible (probably why no one answered).

1. It would be a security risk. If a webpage could browse a folder your personal data could be compromised by a website that started browsing from c drive root.
2. The <*input type="file" ... /*> tag doesn't return the file path information, just the file stream and its metadata anyway, so it's doubt there's some other a HTML entity that can be used to post back file path information on a file upload.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to include all files in specific folders/sub-folders.....check on the link below:

http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/javascript-dhtml-ajax/threads/144152/how-to-list-all-files-in-a-folder-including-subfolder-files

Comment: Thanks, but when I dig down into this reference, it suggests using an ActiveXObject from JScript to achieve the file listing and that's the same as using a plugin except worse because it would only work on I.E. So this doesn't answer my question.

I'm not after suggestions on how to achieve the use case I described but an answer on whether it's possible to achieve without using plugins or other non-standard additions to the browser.

Answer (score 0):

The HTML standard FileOpenDialog is the OS Native one which prompt up from your browser (native code has done in browser development <- this is why u need a plug in to  of it)

The standard (non-plugin) open file dialog will trigger native OS controlled file opener....if the OS does not support Folder/Directory selection, then nothing you can do about that without using plugin (because some of the plugins are written in native code, and you can not use a ClientSide Scripting language to takeover your ur operation system's native control).